# How can i create a death zone in my platformer?

Tags: actionscript-3

By death zone I mean an area such as spikes or a pit where, if my character were to touch it, he would restart back to the beginning of the level and lose a life.Any be greatly appreciated and Happy Holidays!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say `char` is the name of your character, and `deathZone` is the name of your death zone:

```
var life:int = 5; //Character has 5 lives
var startPoint:Point = new Point(0, 0); //Where the character starts

addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, function()
{
    if(char.hitTestObject(deathZone))
    {
        life -= 1;
        char.x = startPoint.x;
        char.y = startPoint.y;
        if(life <= 0)
        {
            trace('yourCharacterIsDead');
        }
    }
});
```

This code will make the character lose one life every time he hits the death zone, and if his lives is less than or equal to zero, it will trace 'yourCharacterIsDead'.  That should get you started.

Also, nobody will just *code your game for you.*  You're very lucky I answered this question, anyways.

Comment: Thank you! I had a very general idea of what to do (hitTest and creating a function) but just couldn't figure out why it wasn't resetting. Next time I guess i'll make sure to either research the topic more or post the little bit of coding I have.

Comment: @Name Your welcome.  But maybe you should learn to convert your actionscript 2 knowledge (I'm guessing since you said hitTest) to as3.  Actually, logic can also help ;)

Comment: @Name  Since you appreciate my answer, it seems you could *upvote it* :)